# unknown type name ‘caddr_t’ error

Tags: c, linux, variables

I am trying to setup a 'shared' memory location using

```
caddr_t mmap_ptr;
```

But am getting an error. Any help? Thanks!

Also

```
mmap_ptr = mmap((caddr_t) 0,   /* Memory Location, 0 lets O/S choose */
    MAX_BUFFER_SIZE,/* How many bytes to mmap */
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, /* Read and write permissions */
    MAP_SHARED,    /* Accessible by another process */
    fid,           /* which file is associated with mmap */
    (off_t) 0);    /* Offset in page frame */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`caddr_t` is a BSD-ism, and an old one at that. Under Linux (and POSIX), [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap) returns a void pointer.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
void *mmap (void *addr,
            size_t length,
            int prot,
            int flags,
            int fd,
            off_t offset);
int munmap (void *addr,
            size_t length);
```

Comment: @Alexander, as I see it, you have two possibilities. One, stay on Linux and use the `void*` type. Two, switch to a BSD variant that supports it. I suspect, if it's your own code, the former would be easier :-)